# Right way to install a C++ library on OSX

Tags: c++, c, macos

Today I wanted to start programming C++ with the following library:
https://developer.mbed.org/handbook/mbed-SDK

I'm new to C, so I started looking around for a guide on how to "install" this library so I can use it with `#include "library.h"`.

I've read that the proper location on OSX is `/usr/local/include` (for the header file) and `/usr/local/lib` for the library.

The zip contains a lot of directories, which contain `*.h` header files but also a lot of `*.o` files are there and some `*.a`, and `*.json` files. The files are organized in a `hal`, `drivers` and (a lot of) `TARGET_*` directories. One of the `TARGET_*` directories is for the dev-board I'm working with.

I tried putting the main `mbed.h` file in `/usr/local/include` and the other files in `usr/local/lib` but it didn't work. I also tried putting everything in both dirs, which also didn't work. Lastly, I tried to add the folder to my `PATH` in `.bash_profile`. None of this worked out.

One thing that did work was the `mbed.h` header file. The includes in this header file are the ones that can't be found..

Where should I put the files, do I need to separate them, can't imagine that..

Or am I missing something in the projects directory?

Comment: There is no "the right way", pick what is more convenient. I would not pollute system directories with 3rdparty stuff. It is hard to clean it away if you change your mind. Keep libraries in a separate directory and refer to the custom paths in your build system instead. The final goal is to make compiler find headers and linker to find libraries.

Comment: If this `.h` file needs additional `.h` files, they all need to be in one of the include directories.

Comment: @Drop Thanks, this sounds logical, I'll use a custom folder. "The final goal is to make compiler find headers and linker to find libraries." Should I do this in the Makefile?

Comment: Yes, in Makefile of whatever build system/IDE you use. Basically, instead of  putting stuff into compiler's default search paths, you need to tell compiler what are the additional paths to search in.

Comment: For OSX you need to install command-line tools, as there are not usual IDE's (IAR, uVISION) - see this explanatory link: https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-cli#adding-bash-tab-completion. This will allow you to do independent work.

Comment: The way to do it depends whether your are developing and building using a GUI such as **Xcode** or whether you are just using `cmake`, or `Makefiles`.

Comment: @Yoan I tried the CLI, it's really slow and when I try to compile it says it can't find the executable for GCC_ARM.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I wanted to keep things simple at first. Just a folder with a `.cpp` file, include the library and compile it.

Comment: So put the header files in `/somewhere/include` and the libraries in `/somewhere/lib` and run `clang++ -I/somewhere/include main.cpp -o main -L/somewhere/lib -llib1.a -llib2.a`